# System of linear equations in 8 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Although I am currently studying fractional linear transformations in complex analysis, I suddenly had the need to find the "solution" of a system of linear equations but I could not. Unless I have made some mistake in the algebra on the way, the system is as follows:

$ac' = a'c$

$ad \ ' +bc' = a'd + b'c$

$bd \ ' = b'd$

Observe from the first and last equation that we have equal ratios. So if I can show that $ab' = a'b$ then this should imply that the variables are multiples of each other by some fixed constant. I am suspecting that I am to use the second equation in some manner (hopefully not brute force using any of the other two) to obtain the desired equality.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So $a,a',b,b'c,c',d$ and $d'$ are the variables you are trying to solve for? Then these equations are not linear. They are homogeneously quadratic, since every term has degree two in unknowns quantities..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate to of the variables and be left with a single equation relating the other 6. But there will still be infinitely many solutions. To eliminate $a'$, I'd multiply the second equation by $c$ so that you can swap out all instances of $a'c$. Then I'd do the same for $b'$, multiplying by $d$ and swapping out the $b'd$.

Comment: Is it possible to show what I want to show? I don't want to solve this, I just want to show that $ab' = a'b$

Comment: No. It's possible for $a=b'=0$ and $a'=b=1$. Just try entering those and see what would be required of the remaining variables.